# Unity3d The UI disappears when pressing the button[Finished]

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am writing an RTS game based on Unity3d. I have created a Canvas for each unit, but this Canvas will only take effect after clicking on the unit, and will be disabled when clicking on other locations or other units.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp5FN.png)

```
public void OnLeftMouseClickSelect(GameObject unit)
    {
        DeselectAll();
        currenSelection_Unit.Add(unit);
        unit.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);//Active the selected circle
        unit.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);//UI Panel active
        unit.GetComponent<UnitBehavior>().enabled=true;
        //ShowCurrentPanel();
    }
public void DeselectAll()
    {
        foreach (var unit in currenSelection_Unit)
        {
            unit.GetComponent<UnitBehavior>().enabled = false;
            unit.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(false);
            unit.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        currenSelection_Unit.Clear();
    }
```

I tried to detect the object returned when I clicked. What I can confirm is that the object obtained when I clicked the button is indeed the button itself. OnClick in the button has also added objects and functions.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRI5S.png)
But in actual testing, when I click the button, the UI will be disabled, and the function in Onclick will not be called. I hope to know how I can modify my code to ensure that the UI will not be disabled when I click on part of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hard to answer due to the lack of context. However I'll try my best at it.

It sounds like you're trying to trigger a button event before the gameObject that has the UI Canvas has enabled. If thats the case, its probably because the UI isn't enabled until the frame ends. Then the button event can trigger on the next frame.

However, you can probably ignore this completely by removing the

```html
.SetActive(false)
```

for both the `DeselectAll()` and `OnLeftMouseClickSelect`.
and look for an alternative way to disable its functionality. One alternative approach is to get the component of the object, and disable/enable that instead. Thats one possibility.

Comment: i used IsPointOverGameObject to fix it,make sure when i click UI part,DeselectAll() will not work,but thank you